# Using openssl with Kohana 3.0 framework returning error

Tags: php, openssl, kohana

The code for my encryption controller is shown below.  This works fine by itself in a separate working directory from my kohana installation.

```
class Controller_Crypt extends Controller_Home
{
    public static function Encrypt_This($sensitive)
    {
    //file path must be relative to directory, also derp.
        $pubkey = openssl_pkey_get_public('file://' . URL::site('../../private/public');
openssl_public_encrypt($sensitive, $cipher, $pubkey);
    return base64_encode($cipher);  
    return $cipher;
    }
    public static function Decrypt_This($cipher, $pass)
    {
     $cipher = base64_decode($cipher);
        //file path must be relative to directory, also derp.
    $prkey = 'file://' . URL::site('../../private/private');
    $privatekey = openssl_pkey_get_private($prkey, $pass);
    openssl_private_decrypt($cipher, $sensitive, $privatekey);

    return $sensitive;
    }
}
```

Though, for some reason I do not understand I am getting this error:

```
ErrorException [ Warning ]: openssl_private_decrypt() [function.openssl-private-decrypt]: key parameter is not a valid private key
```

Once again I have checked this code by itself outside of the kohana application and it works fine, decrypting the $cipher.

I am by no means an expert with using openssl so if anyone knows what the issue is here and could enlighten me I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the documentation on [openssl_pkey_get_private](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php) it appears you need to specify the full (absolute) path.

Using `URL::site` would append `http://` and thus you would get:

```
file://http://localhost/../../private/private
```

which is invalid. I guess that causes your next function call to fail. The solution would be to either

1. Load the private key into a string and pass that or
2. Use a function like [realpath](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.ph) to get the absolute path.

PS: Don't forget to accept correct answers otherwise you'll get a lower response rate in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Pixel has the right diagnosis. You'll end up wanting to something like this:

`openssl_pkey_get_public('file://' .APPPATH. 'private/public');`

The path constants like this are defined in `index.php`.